# Run dotCover for all assemblies in TeamCity build

Tags: nunit, teamcity, resharper, code-coverage, dotcover

I currently have a C# solution running on a TeamCity build and want to measure current code coverage using dotCover. The solution has a few projects that produce assemblies and also a few projects that contain NUnit tests for the other projects. Everything is working well, and I get a code coverage report in TeamCity.

However I noticed that the code coverage does not include some assemblies that are missing unit tests. This results in the code coverage reporting a higher coverage than the actual coverage, since these missing assemblies have 0% coverage. I ran the solution through ReSharper test coverage, and it shows a different code coverage than what's displayed in TeamCity, since it has includes these missing assemblies.

I manually added a new project that contains dummy tests (it references some of the missing assemblies but does not actually do any tests). This makes the missing assemblies show up in the TeamCity code coverage with 0% coverage and the total coverage is now showing the actual coverage.

Is there any way to tell TeamCity/dotCover to show the coverage for all assemblies, regardless whether there are any unit tests referencing them in a similar manner as ReSharper?

Comment: After some more searching I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483960/teamcity-with-dotcover-does-not-include-all-my-assemblies-in-coverage-report) answer whiched helped out.